# What is the best way to automate testing of a messenger app? (Android, iOS and web)

Tags: ios, automation, messenger

We plan to automate the tests for a messenger app that we are building. Since it needs 2 simulators, what is the best way to automate it? Would automating the communication between App and backend a better option?

Comment: do you find any solution? I can't find best practices for this problem in google at all!

Comment: If you want to be cross platform, you could refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564111/can-i-work-with-2-simulators-ios-and-android-in-a-single-test-case-using-calab