# Can I work with 2 simulators (iOS and Android) in a single test case using Calabash?

Tags: calabash

Is it possible to work with 2 simulators for executing single test case using calabash? If yes how do we launch 2 simulators and manage the session?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily do that simply using calabash x-platform solution. Please use official calabash article for reference and detailed instruction - it contains all info you need. 
https://github.com/calabash/x-platform-example

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was referring to more like a messaging app where in a single test case I send a message from one simulator and verify it is received on the other simulator in a single test case. The link seems to be about writing one test case which would work for both iOS and Android. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have a previously written an answer about doing this here - [Running and communicating Calabash android and calabash iOS together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130469/running-and-communicating-calabash-android-and-calabash-ios-together/35174204#35174204)

Have a look and hopefully it will help you :)

Comment: This is what I was looking for..Thanks so much for your help.. I will try it and let you know how I get on.. :)

Comment: No problem!  Let me know if there are any issues with it.  I wrote it from memory so it will be good to have it tested :)  Also it wasn't ever accepted as an answer, so if it works for you definitely leave a comment on the question.